# Comparing data from two classes

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Let’s say I have the following dataset:

```
Student Age Class
1 23 Maths
2 26 Physics
3 24 Maths
4 24 Maths
5 28 Physics
…
```

I plotted it considering the relative frequencies (y-axis) and age on x-axis:
[image]

Where line 1 is Maths and line 2 is Physics.
The number of obs in each class is different (200 in Maths vs 100 in Physics).
What would it be a good test to see if these two distributions/samples are similar or not?

Comment: You have the plots and can see the similarities and differences. What more do you need from your analysis, a p-value of distribution equality?

Comment: You can check if the "Kullback–Leibler divergence" helps with your problem.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your comments. I would like to find a way to explain similarity and differences between the plots. I was wondering if there is a test that can also justify similarities/differences between the two plots

Comment: Any answer that could help me to explain the plots above would be extremely helpful, especially if supported by a test that can give more strength to justify the  results. Thanks

Comment: The two distributions seem to be of about the same shape. Even with sample sizes in the 100's, some may feel distributions are too skewed (to far from normal) to use a t test. If not t, then two-sample nonparametric Wilcoxon rank sum test will tell you whether locations are significantly different. // However, I tend to agree with @Dave that comparing histograms may tell you all you really need to know. // If physicists are a bit older in this year's classes, mathematicians may be a bit older next year. Or is your real problem something else, disguised as ages in majors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results from R for fictitious data, illustrating my Comment:

```
set.seed(2022)
mat = round(rgamma(200, 20, 1)) + 10
phy = round(rgamma(100, 20, 1)) + 12
summary(mat)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  21.00   27.00   30.00   30.05   33.00   44.00 
summary(phy)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   22.0    29.0    31.5    32.1    35.0    49.0
```

A boxplot (math=1, physics=2) shows moderate right-skewness in both samples.

```
boxplot(mat, phy, horizontal=T , col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Both the Welch 2-sample t test and the 2-sample Wilcoxon
rank sum tests show highly significant differences (P-values near $0),$ in a statistical
sense. The real question may be whether the difference in 'ages'
is of any practical importance.

```
t.test(mat, phy)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  mat and phy
t = -3.6995, df = 183.19, p-value = 0.0002855
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.1356328 -0.9543672
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
   30.055    32.100 

wilcox.test(mat, phy)$p.val
[1] 0.0002800143
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and example!